# Pairwise Mutual Independence.

Tags: probability, independence

Let {(Ai, Bi)} for i=1 to n be mutually independent, i.e., (Ai, Bi) is independent of (Aj, Bj ) for every i≠j. Then how to prove that P(A1, . . . , An|B1, . . . , Bn) = Π P(Ai|Bi) for i=1 to n.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=2$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(A_1,A_2\mid B_1,B_2)=\frac{\mathsf{P}(A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2)}{\mathsf{P}(B_1,B_2)}=\frac{\mathsf{P}(A_1,B_1)\mathsf{P}(A_2,B_2)}{\mathsf{P}(B_1)\mathsf{P}(B_2)}=\ldots
$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  But this assumes all Ai's and Bi's are independent of each other. That's how you changed the denominator to the product of individual probabilities. Is there a way to first show that all Ai's and Bi's are independent of each other.

Comment: Nope. It uses the fact that $B_i$ is independent of $B_j$ for $i\ne j$.